# Python Facebook - Upload Image

Tags: python, facebook, upload

I am looking for how to implement a upload in Python, I downloaded the pyFacebook but the documentation is gone and there are a lot of old post on Google.
I wondering if someone has made it or I need to create a facebook app to upload the picture.

I am quiet new on the Python world, so any help , even if it's stupid , it's appreciated.

Comment: Are you building a command line application or a web application with Python?

Comment: I am creating any application with ubuntu quickly, the application is running with GTK as GUI

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with any language using the Facebook Graph API. See this blog post for an example: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/. It's written in `PHP` but the basic Graph API methods are the same in any language as long as you can call a URL with some parameters.

In this case, the call should be a HTTP POST to `https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos` with the params `source` (the photo to upload), `message` (a description of the photo) and `access_token` (the [authentication](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) token you need to post photos).

To make posts with python, take a look at [httplib](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html) or the simpler [requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html).